# Как сделать так, чтобы в КС возвращалcя целый текст, который я ввожу, а не возврат 1 слова?

Tags: java

```
package proverka_script;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Proverka_script {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

  String myString = null;
  Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
  String a = myString;
  a = num.next();
  myString = a;
  String target = "e";
  String replacement = "c";
  String newString = myString.replace(target, replacement);
  int length = newString.length();
  System.out.println(newString + " " + length);

 }
}
```

При вводе информации в консоль, например, Hello World, я получу только "Hcllo" а World теряется. Как быть, возможно стоит использовать `StringBuffer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 

// Считали строку целяком и сразу же
// заменили первую букву на вторую
String str = scanner.nextLine().replace("e", "c");

System.out.println(str + " " + str.length());
```

Comment: В той строке, кстати, изначально не null.

Comment: @post_zeew, а что? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html Что-то там ничего путного не нашел..

Comment: @entithat Значения локальных переменных не определены и их использование без предварительной инициализации не допускается компилятором. Ваш код верен, переменной `str` присваивается значение до использования, но не надо было писать в комментарии  "изначальна равна null" и можно было совместить объявление, инициализацию и замену символов: `String str = scanner.nextLine().replace("e", "c") ;`

Comment: @m.vokhm, кстати да, в этом Вы правы :)